# Execute code on filtering JavaFX TableView rows

Tags: java, javafx, filter, tableview, rows

I'm using a TextFiled to filter rows of a JavaFX TableView which results in a SortedList which is set to the TableView and it works, also I created a function that takes that SortedList as a parameter to do other stuff, The problem is that the SortedList doesn't change value although the filtering is taking effect in the table, does that mean that the filtering hides the rows and not removes them from the TableView initial list, please help , here's my code :

```
FilteredList<CommandeFX> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(commande -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (String.valueOf(commande.getCodeCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;
                 // Filter matches first name.

            } else if (String.valueOf(commande.getCMD()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getClient()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {                                  
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getFournisseur()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getQuantite()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getPrixCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getSommeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getResteCommandeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateReception()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getModified()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            else if (String.valueOf(commande.getValide()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }

            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });


    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<CommandeFX> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);    

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableCommandes.comparatorProperty());
    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    tableCommandes.setItems(sortedData);
    // the function 
    setSum(sortedData);
```

Comment: The sorted list should contain the same elements as the filtered list - I.e. You should see the results of the filtering. What is actually happening that makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: I am seeing the result of the filtering, the fact that the filtered list always has the same size as the original one is my problem but not anymore because that means the rows that don't match the filter are set as empty which kinda gonna resolve my issue, Thank you though !

Comment: I don't really follow that. What is the question? Or do you not have a question any more?

Comment: I need to iterate through the TableView rows after the sorted list is added to it, so I can deal only with the visible rows.

Comment: `for (CommandeFX c : sortedData) { ... }`

Comment: No I asked how to iterate through tableCommandes rows

Comment: That's exactly what that will do. You set `sortedData` as the items for the table.

Comment: I know but I don't need browsing to the objects, I want to iterate through rows (cells)

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and explain exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. The cells are just views of the data. Changing the data will change the cells if you have everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not paying attention that the function I want to to call each time I type in the filter Text-field wasn't in the right place. now the function `getSum(SortedList Commande<FX> list)` is called in real time as I type in the filter. here is the correct code :

```
FilteredList<CommandeFX> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);

// 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    filteredData.setPredicate(commande -> {
        // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
        if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
        String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

        if (String.valueOf(commande.getCodeCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true;
             // Filter matches first name.

        } else if (String.valueOf(commande.getCMD()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getClient()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {                                  
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getFournisseur()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getQuantite()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getPrixCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getSommeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getResteCommandeProperty()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateCommande()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getDateReception()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getModified()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(commande.getValide()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
            return true; // Filter matches last name.
        }

        return false; // Does not match.
    });



      // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
      SortedList<CommandeFX> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);    

      // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
  sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableCommandes.comparatorProperty());
     // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
     tableCommandes.setItems(sortedData);
     // the function 
     setSum(sortedData);

});
```